# how to send values to XML file in runtime using C#

Tags: c#, xml

I want to use the value given by the user in the textbox as value for TestMode in the XMl file.
The XML file looks like below.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="SaveWindowItemsMap" value="true"/>
    <add key="TestMode" value=""/>
</appSettings>
```

The value is to be passed as given by the user(in text box) in runtime and it should not be updated in the XML file.

Comment: What have tried so far, show your code to explain more clearly.

Comment: What do you mean: "it should not be updated in the XML file"?

Comment: Side note: one usually don't "send" values to a file, files are either read or written (opened/parsed/saved...) - are you sure you really mean "send"? Also please check if "it should not be updated in the XML" is correct statement... And adding some code you tried to work with XML (like create `XmlDocument` would go long way in making question better).

Comment: and y are you sending values to xml if you don't want to update the xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try this :

Here is the code sample to modify the application settings value:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

xmlDoc.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);

foreach (XmlElement element in xmlDoc.DocumentElement)
{
    if (element.Name.Equals("appSettings"))
    {
        foreach (XmlNode node in element.ChildNodes)
        {
            if (node.Attributes[0].Value.Equals("SaveWindowItemsMap"))
            {
                node.Attributes[1].Value = "New Value";
            }
        }
    }
}

xmlDoc.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);

ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

I am assuming you want to update "SaveWindowItemsMap" value.